unresolved import rust in workspace with multiple crates
I have a workspace with 3 crates, game_nft, backend and tests.
Here is my root Cargo.toml
[workspace]
members = ["backend", "game_nft", "tests"]
resolver = "2"

My tests/Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "tests"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
candid = "0.10.6"
pocket-ic = "6.0.0"
game_nft = { path = "../game_nft" }

To be very clear, here is the file structure:
root/
├── Cargo.toml
├── Cargo.lock
├── game_nft/
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src/
├── test/
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src/
├── backend/
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src/

In my tests/src/lib.rs I do use game_nft;
So why am I getting the error:
 error[E0432]: unresolved import `game_nft`
 --> tests/src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 | use game_nft;
  |     ^^^^^^^^ no external crate `game_nft`

Here is game_nft/Cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "game_nft"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
candid = "0.10.6"
ic-cdk = "0.13.1"
ic-stable-structures = "0.6.3"
icrc-ledger-types = "0.1.5"
serde = "1.0.197"
icrc-nft-types = { git = "https://github.com/pramitgaha21/icrc-nft-types.git" }
ciborium = "0.2.2"
serde_bytes = "0.11"

I have also tried the syntax use crate::game_nft; and got the same error message.

Could you please show the exact error output from the compiler?

What is the content of root/game_nft/Cargo.toml, and (assuming it's pretty standard) does root/game_nft/src/lib.rs exist?

Yeah its pretty standard and yeah game_nft/src/lib.rs exists.
I will add the cargo to the post
@eggyal

@Silvestr added it.

The crate-type = ["cdylib"] is an issue, other Rust crates can't depend on a cdylib library as a Cargo dependency. Fortunately it is an easy fix, see How do I import a crate-type = ["cdylib"] library?

A cdylib cannot be used from Rust. You can make game_nft (at least) of type lib, dylib, or rlib. You can read more about these here.
So game_nft/Cargo.toml should read:
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]

